# A reference about tangent spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I am aware of a fact that dimension of tangent space to the point on variety has bigger dimension then local dimension of said variety (local with respect to that point). But I do not know where to find some exact theorem, lemma, remark, in some book where that is proven (or even said, I just am writing something where I $\textbf{truly}$ wish not to put something as if I am imagining it from the top of my head). This should be correct for any variety, where "local" dimension should mean dimension of the variety in case that variety is irreducible, and should mean dimension of irreducible component to which a point belongs if variety is reducible.

To automatically avoid the possible questions and negative comments, my point is smooth, and such a point always has unique irreducible component that contains it, look at Remark 10.10 at Andreas Gathmann Class Notes for Algebraic Geometry, free online notes.

So, can you find this lemma for me? Thankies!!!